# Show post count in wordpress instead of page count in wordpress pagination

Tags: pagination

Iam using wordpress numbered pagination function, it works good I have around 800 posts on homepage, every page i show 8 posts.

So when the user clicks on pagination i want to show 1-8 of 800.
1st post out of 8 total 800
then user clicks 2nd page - i want to show 9-16 of 800
how to implement i researched a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
 * Display pagination information in the format "X - Y of Z".
 * 
 * @param object $wp_query Optionally generate string from custom query, defaults to main.
 */
function wpse_106121_posts_count( $wp_query = null ) {
    if ( ! $wp_query )
        global $wp_query;

    $posts = min( ( int ) $wp_query->get( 'posts_per_page' ), $wp_query->found_posts );
    $paged = max( ( int ) $wp_query->get( 'paged' ), 1 );
    $count = ( $paged - 1 ) * $posts;

    printf(
        '%d - %d of %d',
        $count + 1,
        $count + $wp_query->post_count,
        $wp_query->found_posts
    );
}
```

Place the above in your `functions.php`, then call it where you'd like to display the text:

```
<?php wpse_106121_posts_count() ?>
```